# How to send notification (email,notif, log list) about job execution fail to specific user?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

Suppose that one of the job fail to execute repeatedly and error details logged in log files but how send alert (notification, email, or any kind notification) to specific user about this problem?
aspnetboilerplate template aspnet.mvc,angularjs,SPA .apb version 2.3.0

Comment: Catch the exception and send the email? This is too broad...

Comment: add [DisableUnitOfWork] attrib to Execute mthod and then manage unit of work manually ?

Comment: Just call `_unitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChanges()` in a try-catch block, send your email, and then rethrow the exception.

Comment: @aaron yes. Just call code in try catch  block, and send needed notification in catch block